# django-elasticsearch-dsl Mapping for completion suggest field not working

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

This problem has been driving me crazy for days with not solution.

I create a document as follows from my django model.

from django_elasticsearch_dsl import fields

```
@registry.register_document class QuestionDocument(Document):
    complete = fields.CompletionField(attr='title')

    class Index:
        name = 'questions'

    class Django:
        model = QuestionModel
        fields = ['text', 'title']
```

Now i want to perform a completion query like this:

```
matched_questions = list(QuestionDocument.search().suggest("suggestions", word, completion={'field': 'complete'}).execute())
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Field [complete] is not a completion suggest field')
```

I think the problem is that The mapping for this field is not created correctly, but i don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help with this it is literally driving me crazy.

**UPDATE:**

I realized that in my mapping, complete is created as a text field, and i don't know why this is happening or how to fix this. This is my mapping:

```
{
  "questions" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "complete" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "text" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled too with a similar issue.
You should try to declare your `Document` like this:

```
@registry.register_document 
class QuestionDocument(Document):
    title = fields.TextField(
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='standard'),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
        }
     )

    class Index:
        name = 'questions'

    class Django:
        model = QuestionModel
        fields = ['text']
```

then to recover suggests from the title field:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
s = Search(using=client)
query = s.suggest('name_suggestion',"your_prefixword",completion={'field':'title.suggest'})
response = query.execute()
response.suggest['name_suggestion']
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if that do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is being created automatically instead of you creating it with the mappings you need. You need to, before you index any document, create the index. Not sure how this is done in `django_elasticsearch_dsl` but in `elasticsearch_dsl` it would be just calling `QuestionDocument.init()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand the indexing and how it works. What i don't understand is why `complete` has been mapped to a `text` field and not a `completion` field as i explicitly declared it to be?

Comment: because you only declared it in python and haven't send that declaration to elasticsearch so elasticsearch just generated a mapping for you - it saw a field containing some string and for that the default mapping is a `text` field with a `keyword` multi-field